# How to calculate server performance of a website using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

i am using *jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector* to record performance of

https://jpetstore.cfapps.io/catalog

but it is showing

> ERROR: java.net.UnknownHostException: jpetstore.cfapps.io/catalog

i have installed my serveragent in D: drive

Comment: show your HTTP Request definition

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding concept of the [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/).

1. You need to install the Server Agent not on your machine, you need to install it on the machine where `jpetstore.cfapps.io` application is running
2. Looking into [`host` command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/host.htm) output `jpetstore.cfapps.io` is deployed on 2 machines:

   [image: JMeter host command]
3. Looking into [`whois` command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uwhois.htm) output it appears that the machines are living in Amazon, most probably in they're virtual machines in [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)

   [image]

So if you want to monitor the health of the `jpetstore.cfapps.io` you need to install Server Agent on above 2 hosts and use IP addresses instead of hostname in the PerfMon Metrics Collector. See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more details.

---

If you are not looking for some specific metrics it might be easier to use [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/)